# How to access calls to self from python class functions

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming, self

Concretely, I have a user-defined class of type

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, bar):
    self.bar = bar

  def bind(self):
    val = self.bar
    do_something(val)
```

I need to:

1) be able to call on the class (not an instance of the class) to recover all the `self.xxx` attributes defined within the class.

For an instance of a class, this can be done by doing a `f = Foo('')` and then `f.__dict__`. Is there a way of doing it for a class, and not an instance? If yes, how? I would expect `Foo.__dict__` to return `{'bar': None}` but it doesn't work this way.

2) be able to access all the `self.xxx` parameters called from a particular function of a class. For instance I would like to do `Foo.bind.__selfparams__` and recieve in return `['bar']`. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: How would you get `Foo.__dict__['bar']` ? It is an object attribute, not a class attribute (it is `self.bar`)

Comment: As people usually respond on #python @ freenode: "tell us what you really need to achive".

Comment: @Paco,@Erik: I come from a java background, so I regularly forget that Python is a dynamic language and thus doesn't create a frame of instructions into which it sticks the data given by the user. Thanks for your answers. I will try to find a different way of doing what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that is quite hard to do in a dynamic language, assuming I understand correctly what you're trying to do. Essentially this means going over all the instances in existence for the class and then collecting all the set attributes on those instances. While not infeasible, I would question the practicality of such approach both from a design as well as performance points of view.

More specifically, you're talking of "all the self.xxx attributes defined within the class"—but these things are not defined at all, not at least in a single place—they more like "evolve" as more and more instances of the class are brought to life. Now, I'm not saying all your instances are setting different attributes, but they might, and in order to have a reliable generic solution, you'd literally have to keep track of anything the instances might have done to themselves. So unless you have a static analysis approach in mind, I don't see a clean and efficient way of achieving it (and actually even static analysis is of no help generally speaking in a dynamic language).

A trivial example to prove my point:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # statically analysable
        self.bla = 3

        # still, but more difficult
        if SOME_CONSTANT > 123:
            self.x = 123
        else:
            self.y = 321

    def do_something(self):
        import random
        setattr(self, "attr%s" % random.randint(1, 100), "hello, world of dynamic languages!")

    foo = Foo()
    foo2 = Foo()
    # only `bla`, `x`, and `y` attrs in existence so far
    foo2.do_something()
    # now there's an attribute with a random name out there
    # in order to detect it, we'd have to get all instances of Foo existence at the moment, and individually inspect every attribute on them.
```

And, even if you were to iterate all instances in existence, you'd only be getting a snapshot of what you're interested, not all possible attributes.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is not possible. The class doesn't *have* those attributes, just functions that set them. Ergo, there is nothing to retrieve and this is impossible.
2. This is only possible with deep AST inspection. `Foo.bar.func_code` would normally have the attributes you want under `co_freevars` but you're looking up the attributes on `self`, so they are not free variables. You would have to decompile the bytecode from `func_code.co_code` to AST and then walk said AST.

This is a bad idea. Whatever you're doing, find a different way of doing it.

Comment: AST inspection doesn't help either, in corner cases, so it's not a generic solution. The only reliable (but slow and ugly) solution would physically inspect all instances in existence.

Comment: That's true but I doubt those corner cases would ever come up. Not that it matters, 'cause AST inspection is a silly idea.

Comment: By AST do you mean Abstract Syntax Tree? Just trying to understand your 2nd point.

Comment: Yup. AST == Abstract Syntax Tree.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need some way to find all the instances of your class. One way to do this is just to have the class itself keep track of its instances. Unfortunately, keeping a reference to every instance in the class means that those instances can never be garbage-collected. Fortunately, Python has `weakref`, which will keep a reference to an object but does not count as a reference to Python's memory management, so the instances can be garbage-collected as per usual.

A good place to update the list of instances is in your `__init__()` method. You could also do it in `__new__()` if you find the separation of concerns a little cleaner.

```
import weakref

class Foo(object):

    _instances = []

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

        cls = type(self)
        type(self)._instances.append(weakref.ref(self, 
                                                 type(self)._instances.remove))

    @classmethod
    def iterinstances(cls):
        "Returns an iterator over all instances of the class."
        return (ref() for ref in cls._instances)

    @classmethod
    def iterattrs(cls, attr, default=None):
        "Returns an iterator over a named attribute of all instances of the class."
        return (getattr(ref(), attr, default) for ref in cls._instances)
```

Now you can do this:

```
f1, f2, f3 = Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)

for v in Foo.iterattrs("value"):
    print v,   # prints 1 2 3
```

I am, for the record, with those who think this is generally a bad idea and/or not really what you want. In particular, instances may live longer than you expect depending on where you pass them and what that code does with them, so you may not always have the instances you think you have. (Some of this may even happen implicitly.) It is generally better to be explicit about this: rather than having the various instances of your class be stored in random variables all over your code (and libraries), have their primary repository be a list or other container, and access them from there. Then you can easily iterate over them and get whatever attributes you want. However, there may be use cases for something like this and it's possible to code it up, so I did.